# where is newly created page located in magento 2.0

Tags: magento2, page

Iam very new to magento.
I have created a new page in magento using admin. 
and the url is working fine.
but, can I see the file created for my new page. 
I have to add code in it. I dont know where it located.

what are the files created when a new page created?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which type of code you want to put in page ??

Comment: depends on needs. may be css, may be javascipt, may be extra html tags etc. basically I want to know where it is located.

Comment: this page is stored in data base

Comment: okay, when I give URL localhost/second_page, what is the flow then? like controller, route, view etc.

Comment: call you page using url-key

Comment: sorry to ask you again. what my thinking is, somewhere there is a routing file, it route to a controller -> the controller fetch data from db based on the url key->and render view. is this correct? then where is that controller and route located?

Comment: it really confusing the folders.

Comment: there is no folder named as `code` in `app` folder

Comment: maybe you should read the documentation first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **There is no file created.**
>
> **Page are stored in the database in the table cms_page**

Comment: okay, when I give URL `localhost/second_page`, what is the flow then? like controller, route, view etc.

Comment: maybe you should read the documentation first